# Select2: How to prevent tags sorting

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

When user selects many items (tags), they are automatically sorted alphabetically. How to prevent automatic sort and keep user's order using Select2 4.0?

Update:

The mentioned "possible dublicate question" is for the older version of Select2 v3... I ask about version 4... It differs form older ones and mentioned answers dosn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I've found a solution that works with Select2 v4. It changes the order of items - item selected by user are moved to the end.

```js
$("select").select2();

$("select").on("select2:select", function (evt) {
  var element = evt.params.data.element;
  var $element = $(element);
  
  $element.detach();
  $(this).append($element);
  $(this).trigger("change");
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.js"></script>

<select style="width: 500px;" multiple="multiple">
  <option>two</option>
  <option>four</option>
  <option>six</option>
</select>
```

**Update**

The solution was found here: [github.com/select2/select2/issues/3106](http://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3106). Its author is kevin-brown.

Comment: You should credit where you found the solution: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3106

Comment: @vol7ron Yes, you are right. I couldn't found where I had found the solution, but you've found it.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the original location, but it helps to credit the author and also follow up with them if there's a bug in the solution. As mentioned on GitHub this will reorder the options list, which may not be desired. There's a different workaround there that reorders the tags and preserves the options list order.

Comment: No doubt, you are a life saver. In my case I just needed the first line of your code (var evt.params.data.element;) to send the selected value through ajax. This because (this.value) always brings the value of the very first element selected. :D ;)

Comment: This changes the order of the dropdown when `closeOnSelect` is set to false

Comment: This is rearranging the dropdown list also.. I dont want the dropdown list to change. I want to remove the alphabetic order from the input box only. Is there a workaround for that ?

Comment: Did anyone find a solution that doesn't also re-arrange the order of the dropdown list?

Comment: I found a good solution for the dropdown sort problem:
https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3106?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container#issuecomment-838256359

Comment: This solution still reorders the selected options on page load

Answer (score 2):

This [has been discussed before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21876839/3464552) for Select2 3.5.2, you can use `select2('data')` to get the order.

```js
$("select").select2();

$('#sayResult').click(function () {
  // 'data' brings the unordered list, while val does not
  var data = $('select').select2('data');
  
  // Push each item into an array
  var finalResult = data.map(function () {
    return this.id;
  });

  // Display the result with a comma
  alert( finalResult.join(',') );
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.js"></script>

<select style="width: 500px;" multiple="multiple">
  <option>two</option>
  <option>four</option>
  <option>six</option>
</select>

<button id='sayResult'>Say Result</button>
```

Comment: That code is not working. It uses old version of Select2 v3.4.5

Comment: This does not work in Select2 4.0.0 because `data` now returns the selected items in the order that they appear.

Answer (score 2):

This solution works best

HTML

```
<select style="width: 500px;" multiple="multiple">
    <option>two</option>
    <option>four</option>
    <option>six</option>
  </select>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready( function () {

    $("select").select2({
      tags: true
    });
    
    $("select").on("select2:select", function (evt) {
      var element = evt.params.data.element;
      var $element = $(element);
      
      $element.detach();
      $(this).append($element);
      $(this).trigger("change");
    });

} );
```