# How to prevent automatic sorting in select2 tags (v4)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm creating a project which uses a multiple select2. It's all fine, the problem is I have to prevent the tags (and its result data array) from automatically sorting. I've searched through them but most answers are for older versions of select. Is there a flag or something for this in select2 that I don't know about?

```
$.getJSON("countries.json").done( function(data) {
       $(".country-select").select2({
            placeholder: "Select Country",
            allowClear: true,
            data: data,
            maximumSelectionLength: 5
        })

$(".country-select").change(function() { 
    var selected = $(".country-select").select2('data');
}
```

That is my code, and I want to get all unsorted data to be stored in selected. I found a solution in [Select2: How to prevent tags sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31431197/select2-how-to-prevent-tags-sorting) but it appends the selected element at the end of the options.

Comment: I am thinking that the sorting is coming from your query `data: data,` is there a way you could post that as well

Comment: It's not clear what the current sorting is and what the desired sorting would be. Select2 should sort selections based on how they appear in your original `data` array.

Comment: Sorry guys, what I meant by this is that I wanted the "selected" data to be unsorted the way they appear in the tags. Not the actual selections. For example, if I select Canada, then Algeria, I want the order to be Canada-Algeria. But it seems that select2 automatically sorts this. It becomes Algeria-Canada.