# Select2 v4 .val() does not maintain order of elements in data object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I have a select2 (v4) select box where people are choosing codes, and the order must be maintained. This works great when they originally add the elements:
[image]

However, this is a popup that is used for many different elements on the page. That means I must clear this array and load it with stored data objects on the fly.

My data object preserves the order as `var codeArray = ['7990', '268']`.

But when I use:

```
$(element).val(codeArray).trigger("change")
```

I get the following:

[image]

How can I maintain the order on load? Is there a sneaky workaround?

Comment: i guess this gives a bit clue...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31431197/select2-how-to-prevent-tags-sorting

Comment: Thanks @RohitS, I think that helped.

Comment: happy to help..and dont forget to upvote the answer in thread and the answerer.. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the fix was pretty hacky, but I'll post what I have:

```
function rebuildForm(codeArray) {
  clearFormContents();
  $.each(codeArray, function(j,obj){
    var found = false;
      code_list.some(function(el){
        if (el.value == obj) {
            var str = (el.text).split(")");
            $("element option[value=" + el.value + "]").remove();
            $(element).append(new Option("(" + el.value + ")" + str[1] , obj));
            found = true;
        }
      })
      if (!found) {
        $(element).append(new Option("(" + obj + ") Custom Tag" , obj));
      }
    $(element).val(codeArray).trigger("change");
}
```

Sorry if the above code doesn't work perfectly, I had to clean it up to remove some fluff and hide the client/project identity.

Basically, on the rebuild of the form, I clear the old form contents then loop through the array grabbing each value/object. Then, if the value exists in the original code list of options in the select2 element I delete the option and rebuild it. This appends it to the bottom of the element list so that the order is maintained in the box. I also add any free form text tags using the 'found' boolean.

Once the new list of options are created in the "correct" order, then I am able to add the values back into the select input DOM element and trigger the select2 change to build the tags.

This thread posted by @RohitS in the comments showed the concept: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3106

I just adapted it to my needs.