# how to avoid automatic sorting in multiple select in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a importing json data to the multiple select. But I want to avoid the auto sorting in this multiple select. 
Here is my json data

```
{
"1": "१ ",
"2": "२ ",
"3": "३",
"4": "४ ",
"5": "५ ",
"6": "६ ",
"7": "७ ",
"8": "८ ",
"9": "९ ",
"10": "१० ",
"11": "११",
"12": "१२ ",
"13": "१३ ",
"14": "१४",
"15": "१५",
"16": "१६ ",
"17": "१७ ",
"18": "१८",
"19": "१९ ",
"20": "२०",
"21": "२१",
"22": "२२ ",
"23": "२३",
"24": "२४ ",
"25": "२५ ",
"26": "२६ ",
"27": "२७",
"28": "२८ ",
"29": "२९ ",
"30": "३०"
}
```

and this is my html code

```
 <select ng-model= "wards" aria-controls="example1"
         class="form-control form-control-sm multiple=""
         ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in optionDataWards">
 </select>
```

is there any way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean "avoid automatic sorting"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select2: How to prevent tags sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31431197/select2-how-to-prevent-tags-sorting)

Comment: Instead of an object source, use an array like `[{key: '01', value: 'val for 01'}, {key: '02', value: 'val for 02'}]`?